# Firefox crashes after running JUnit tests with Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, firefox, junit

I am running some `JUnit` tests with `Selenium Web Driver` using `Firefox`.  The tests work fine but after the tests finish (the amount of time after varies) `Firefox` quits working and I get an "an unhandled win32 exception occurred" error.  I set up a separate profile for `Firefox` to use with `Selenium` as show at [Creating a Firefox profile for Selenium Tests](https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/).  I open the browser with the following code.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void loginToSearchPage() throws Exception {
    profile = new ProfilesIni();
    ffprofile = profile.getProfile("Selenium");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Users\\pondek\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")), ffprofile);

    //Open the URL in firefox browser
    driver.get("https://nrijctdu0055710:9449/llr/welcome.action");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    (new Thread(new LoginWindow())).start(); 
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();

}
```

Any ideas on what is going on would be appreciated.